# Cefsharp error at start up and shutdown

Tags: c#, chromium-embedded, cefsharp

> Here is a screenshot of the error:

[image]

If I change the dll to a newer one it doesn't load up at all. A microsoft .net framework window flashes for half a second.

If I click continue the program loads up but all cefsharp components don't work.

Answer (score 0):

According to https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/wiki/Frequently-asked-questions#Runtime_dependencies:

> **Why do I get an error about "Could not load file or assembly 'CefSharp.Core.dll' or one of its dependencies. The specified module
>   could not be found." when trying to run my CefSharp-based application?
>   It compiles successfully, but does not run? It runs on my developer
>   machine, though throws an exception when I copy it to another
>   computer?**
>
> This is a common error, typically one of the following
>
> 1. VC++ 2012/2013 Redistributable Package is required in order to run
>      CefSharp on non developer machines. See FAQ #6 below for more
>      information. You can include the required dlls as part of your
>      application.
> 2. Not all dependencies are present in the executing folder. CefSharp
>      includes unmanaged dll's and resources, these are copied to the
>      executing folder via two .props file which are included in your
>      project when you install the Nuget packages. See list of required
>      files below, make sure the required files are present.
> 3. You packaged your application for distribution via an installer and
>      it doesn't run on the target machine. Installers don't include the
>      unmanaged resources by default, you'll need to add them manually.
>      For ClickOnce, see #1314 for some pointers and solutions other users
>      have come up with.

So, I would recommend reading that and trying those suggestions.